# Why does the $_POST superglobal no contain data from the http request entity?

Tags: php, android, kotlin, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am transitioning my project's network code from using HttpUrlConnection and GET requests to using Apache HttpClient and POST requests.  The setup for my post request is (in kotlin)

```
val client = HttpClients.createDefault()
val postReq = HttpPost("http://VALID_DOMAIN/app/posttest.php")
postReq.entity = HttpEntities.create("tst=1234")
val response = client.execute(postReq) { return@execute EntityUtils.toString(it.entity) }
```

The file posttest.php on the server:

```
<?php
$get = $_GET['tst'];
$post = $_POST['tst'];
$request = $_REQUEST['tst'];

echo "This Server Says \n_GET: $get \n_POST: $post \n_REQUEST: $request";

?>
```

However, noting is printed after the colons where where should be the output of the parameter 'tst'.  I have checked the server error logs and made sure everything compiled correctly and cannot identify the issue.

Comment: You should double check your logs or whether anything is written there at all. Because at least one of statements should produce a Warning

Comment: there was a warning, but that is just evident of the problem that the data in the request is not being received properly, and I doubt there are errors in this very simple test php script.

Comment: try file_get_contents('php://input'); if it's empty, you are doing something wrong in the Kotlin side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will only try and populate the `$_POST` superglobal in case the `Content-Type` of the HTTP POST is either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

I am not a kotlin developer, but it looks to me you need to either set the `Content-Type` explicit or use `UrlEncodedFormEntity` like this (which might set the `Content-Type` header for you):

```kotlin
val urlParameters: MutableList<NameValuePair> = ArrayList()
urlParameters.add(BasicNameValuePair("tst", "123"))
postReq.entity = UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters)
```

In either case, you can always see the entire HTTP request headers in PHP in the `$_SERVER` superglobal (just `var_dump($_SERVER)`). They are prefixed with `HTTP_`, so you will see the `Content-Type`-header in `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']`.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.post-description